# GitHub Wiki markdown editing: how to avoid substitution of "\033"?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I am editing a Wiki page on GitHub using the Markdown edit mode and trying to insert a block of code form a shell script as follows:

````
```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```
````

However, the block ends up looking like this instead:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[SAME-43-CHAR-SEQUENCE[01;32m\]\u@\h\[SAME-43-CHAR-SEQUENCE[00m\]:\[SAME-43-CHAR-SEQUENCE[01;34m\]\w\[SAME-43-CHAR-SEQUENCE[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

So it looks like it's interpreting the char sequence `\033` as some sort of code `SAME-43-CHAR-SEQUENCE` which looks like some sort of UUID. How can I avoid that? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the slash with another slash seems to work.

So, change `\033` to `\\033`

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\\033[00m\]:\[\\033[01;34m\]\w\[\\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```